# Was machen wir mit einem Benutzer, der uns mit schlechten Fragen bombardiert?

Tags: discussion, community-moderation, questions, low-quality-posts

Zurzeit bombardiert ein Nutzer German Language SE mit einer schlecht gestellten und nahezu nicht recherchierten Frage nach der anderen. 
Beinahe jeder seiner Fragen wird erst mal von irgendjemandem formatiert, damit sie überhaupt lesbar ist, und ist dann immer recht schnell und einfach zu beantworten.

Er scheint sich speziell mit dem Finanzwesen auseinanderzusetzen und benutzt unsere Seite, um für ihn Textstellen zu übersetzen, die er nicht versteht.

Die meisten Fragen zeigen nicht mal den geringsten Aufwand, damit er sie selbst beantworten kann.

Wie gehen wir mit so einem Nutzer um?

Comment: Die Fragen beziehen sich alle auf genau 1 Buch. Mittlerweile sind wir bei Kapitel 2 und zu gefühlt jedem 3. Absatz taucht eine Frage auf. Mir stellt sich da auch die Frage, ob und wie man einen Hinweis geben sollte, dass ein Text zu schwer ist und man besser was anderes lesen sollte. Ohne die Person zu demotivieren oder vom lesen weiterer deutscher Texte abzuhalten.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Auf Stack Exchange gibt es automatische Mechanismen, die Nutzer mit einer Historie an geschlossenen oder schlechtbewerteten Fragen drosseln oder gar [ganz davon abhalten](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), neue Fragen zu stellen.

Diese Mechanismen funktionieren allerdings nur, wenn die entsprechenden Fragen auch tatsächlich downgevotet oder geschlossen werden.
(Ich bitte dies nicht als Aufforderung zu verstehen, jetzt zu beginnen, alle Fragen dieses Nutzers zu schließen oder zu downzuvoten – sondern nur, wenn dies auch wirklich angemessen ist.)

Bei einem kurzen Blick über die Fragen dieses Nutzers ist mir unter anderem Folgendes aufgefallen, dass wir hätten tun können oder sollen:

- Fragen, die mehrere Einzelfragen enthalten:

  - in Kommentaren darauf hinweisen, warum das schlecht ist
  - als *too broad* schließen oder (wenn möglich) auf eine Frage reduzieren
  - vor allem: nicht alle Fragen beantworten
- Fragen, die von einem Wörterbuch beantwortet werden können, oder nicht klarstellen, wieso ein Wörterbuch keine Antwort liefert:

  - mit dem entsprechenden Grund schließen
  - in Kommentaren nach Verbesserungen fragen
  - nicht beantworten (auch nicht in den Kommentaren)
- Fragen, die keine eigentliche Frage enthalten, oder wo nicht klar ist, wieso dem Fragesteller etwas unklar ist:

  - als unklar schließen
  - oder: editieren, um sie auf (akzeptierte) Antworten zuzuschneiden
  - in Kommentaren nach Verbesserungen fragen
  - nicht beantworten (auch nicht in den Kommentaren)
- Fragen mit passenden Tags versehen (nicht nur [meaning-in-context](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context)).
- Antworten in Kommentaren u. Ä. flaggen.

Schließlich haben auch wir Moderatoren Möglichkeiten, einzelne Nutzer in ihre Schranken zu weisen.

Comment: So sehe ich das auch: **schlechte Fragen bitte nicht beantworten, auch nicht in Kommentaren**. Das gilt aber bei allen Fragen aller Benutzern und sollte nicht nur bei einem einzelnen Benutzer angewandt werden!

Comment: (Deutsch:) Meines erachtens gibt es auch für solche Fälle, wo ein Benutzer die automatischen Filter/Sperren nicht erreicht, einen Suspendierungsgrund: *for low-quality contributions*. (Englisch:) If I recall correctly, there is a suspension reason for exactly this case: A user posts a lot of low-quality contents but not enough to reach the question block: *for low-quality contributions*.

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty...: Japp, darauf spielte mein letzter Satz an.

Comment: Nun, vielleicht schafft es ja dieser Nutzer, die Anderen dazu zu erziehen, nicht in Kommentaren zu antworten...